# Parse server fulltext search is not working on pointer column?

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, mongodb-query, parse-server

I am using parse server with mlab on heroku, I have two table linked 1. Artist 2. Offer

Each offer have an pointer column `artist`.

I have created a text index, here is the view:

```
  "v": 2,
  "key": {
    "_fts": "text",
    "_ftsx": 1
  },
  "name": "OfferSearchIndex",
  "ns": "heroku_46tdsp6m.Offer",
  "weights": {
    "_p_artist": 1,
    "_p_artist.firstname": 1,
    "_p_artist.lastname": 1,
    "category": 1,
    "drscription": 1,
    "drscription_de": 1,
    "drscription_fr": 1,
    "drscription_it": 1,
    "drscription_ru": 1,
    "medium": 1,
    "movement": 1,
    "title": 1,
    "title_de": 1,
    "title_fr": 1,
    "title_it": 1,
    "title_ru": 1
  },
  "default_language": "english",
  "language_override": "language",
  "textIndexVersion": 3
}
```

Now I have below cloud query to search offer:

```
  var offerQuery = new Parse.Query("Offer");
  offerQuery.include('artist');
  offerQuery.fullText('artist.firstname', request.params.wildcard);
 return offerQuery.find({
                    useMasterKey: true
                
            }, function(error) {
                console.log('#getOfferForAdmin error 1', error);
                return error;
            })
```

But this query not searching offer based on artist firstname and lastname. It is returning only those records that match offer title, offer description.

I used below command to create a in dex:

```
db.Offer.createIndex( { "_p_artist": "text","_p_artist.firstname": "text", "_p_artist.lastname": "text", title: "text", title_de: "text", title_fr: "text", title_it: "text", title_ru: "text", drscription: "text",  drscription_de: "text", drscription_fr: "text", drscription_it: "text", drscription_ru: "text",  category: "text", medium: "text", movement: "text" }, {name:"OfferSearchIndex"}, { default_language:"none" } )
```

Comment: For reference cross-posted on GitHub (issue has been closed) - https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/6862

Comment: @TomFox Thanks for the edit suggest, Actually I did not reecive any solution on stackoverflow so that's why I creat ed a issue on the github, and also there is noi such doicumentation available on parse server regarding the text index and the pointer column index.

Comment: I see that but there is no guarantee of an answer on any timescale - that's open source for you. We don't accept questions on GitHub (SO was the right place to post this) - as you will have noticed having removed the contents of the issue template. If you still haven't received an answer in a week, you could try posting on our [community forum](https://community.parseplatform.org) but please provide a link back to this post so that people can check to see if it has already received an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to run the text search using the fields of the inner object. The best chance for you is to run the text search in the Artist class and use this query as a subquery of a main query at the Offer class.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo I tried this using OR QUERY but we can not use 2 fulltext in a query.

Comment: I also tried solution listed here  :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51767187/mongodb-indexing-for-a-parse-server-application?noredirect=1&lq=1 but not working as expected

Comment: So I believe you will have actually to run two different queries.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo I have around 250K records in artist and if I run two queries then how we can handle a pagination. Bevause both Offers and Artist have large number of records.

Comment: For this high number of objects, I'd try another way. Two suggestions: - integrate to a specialized elastic search service (it will probably give you the best performance) - denormalize the objects that you have in the artist class, copying their information that you need to search for also to the offers class, maybe using an aftersave trigger.

Comment: I think using mongo specific query  we can achieve this Is this possible to run a direct mongo query via https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose? Or this will cause any security and performance issue?